# handling multiple constant socket connections simultaneously

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, asynchronous

I want to write a chat application in java which can handle many users simultaneously. I read about sockets and threadpools to limit thread number, but I can't imagine how to handle e.g. 100 socket connections at the same time and do not create 100 new threads. Idea is that client connects at the beginning and his connection stays opened until he leaves the chat. He can send data to server as well as receive other users messages.

Read from socket is blocking operation, so I would need to check all user's sockets in loop with some timeout if new data is available in particular socket connection? My first idea was to create e.g. 3 threads for handling input from all connected users and 3 threads for outcomming communication from server to clients, but how can I achieve that? Is there any async API for sockets in Java where can I define threadpools for in/out communication?

Comment: If you don't need to reinvent the wheel, I would suggest you take a look at [Netty](http://netty.io/) which abstracts away a great deal of this.

Answer (score 1):

**Make a `Client` class that extends `Thread`**. Write all the methods and in the `void run()` method, write the code you want executed when the client connection is made.

On the `Server` side, listen for new connections. Accept a new connection, get the information about the connection, pass it in the constructor to **create a new `Client` object, and add it to an `ArrayList`** to keep track of all ongoing connections and execute the `start()` method. So, all the `Client` objects are in an `Arraylist`, and the they keep running at the same time.

I had made such a chat application about an year ago. And do not forget to close the connection once the Client disengages, orelse all the objects pile up and slow up the application. I learnt that the hard way.

Comment: Using a single thread per client is an anti-pattern. Yes, it will work absolutely fine for 10, 20, or maybe 100 clients, but it will degrade significantly as the number of clients increases. Non-blocking I/O (either by using Netty, another library, or Java NIO directly) is going to give you much better long term performance.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you completely. But, I dont think that he is going to build a commercial application with many clients. This is a simple solution that can get him started. As long as each connection is  closed properly after each use, it will work well. And as per my use, It worked just fine with 53 connections. When I experimented it with my class in college.Still I would like to know of a better way. I will check out those libraries. But building something from scratch all on your own is well, rewarding. :)

Comment: It's a bad practice to create 1 thread per client and I wrote that in my question, so your answer is pointless.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Netty](http://netty.io/) as it provides an NIO framework (non-blocking IO) so that you do not need 1 thread per connection.  It is a little bit (or a lot..) more complicated to write a server using non-blocking IO, but there are performance gains in regards to not requiring one thread per connection.

However, 100 threads is not so many, so you could still create your server using standard IO and one thread per connection, it just depends on how much you need to scale.

For a server setup using Netty, you create a channel to which new connections are assigned.  This channel is an ordered series of handlers which process incoming (and outgoing) messages from a connection / client.  The handlers themselves all need to be asynchronous such that when a handler needs to return a message to the client it writes it asynchronously (non-blockingly) to the channel and receives a future back to which it can attach actions for when the message is actually written.

There is a little bit of a learning curve, but it is not that steep and the overall design of your application will be much better if built the Netty way vs using standard blocking IO.